# I am using *ngFor to iterate element in a card layout. I want to randomly change their background color Is there any way?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ngfor

Below it the HTML Part where data from remote server is fetched.

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4" *ngFor="let material of materials" >
    <div class="card widget-statstic-card"  >
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="card-header-left">
          <h3 class="d-inline-block">{{material.Prd_Type}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="text-left">
          <h3 class="d-inline-block">

          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the TS I have given a function which returns colors from the colors array defined in ts. Here the problem is the *ngFor loops keeps on repeating again & again & all colors are changing i dont want them to change again & again.

```
colors=['red','blue','green'];

  materials: any;
  randomItem: string;
  constructor(public http: HttpService) {
    this.http.getMethod('ProductType/get').subscribe((data => {
      this.materials = data;
      console.log(this.materials);
    }));
  }

  getColor(){
     this.randomItem = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.colors.length)];
     console.log('s',this.randomItem);
     return this.randomItem;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getColor();
  }
```

Comment: Should the colors only be randomized once per load, or more often?

Comment: Also, where are you actually setting the background color?  You don't seem to be actually using the random value anywhere.

Comment: You only these are the three colors? Is two color is ok? In default ngFor provides odd or even function you can use like this to change background color maybe.

Comment: Now colors array has seven colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background color using `[style.background]="color"`;

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4" *ngFor="let material of materials" >
    <div class="card widget-statstic-card"  [style.background]="getColor()">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="card-header-left">
          <h3 class="d-inline-block">{{material.Prd_Type}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="text-left">
          <h3 class="d-inline-block">

          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nicc9) is a working example for this.

Comment: Brother i copied your code as it is in my project but still that colors are keeping on changing

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: You exactly got my point & your code is working fine. But here in my project the code & colors keeps chagning

Comment: Can you share the stackblitz with me?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only want the colors to be randomized every time you fetch data, you should do the randomization at that point:

```
this.http.getMethod('ProductType/get').subscribe((data => {
  this.materials = data.map(material => {
    // assumes your data doesn't already have a "color" property
    material.color = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.colors.length)]
    return material
  };
  console.log(this.materials);
}));
```

I can't tell where you're actually setting the background color in your code, but it'll look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4" *ngFor="let material of materials" [style.background]="material.color">
```

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're calling the `getColor` inside your loop, by if the loop is what causes the `getColor` to be called each time, you can use `trackBy` function to avoid unexpected changing of color.

In your **template** file

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4" *ngFor="let material of materials; trackBy: trackByFn" >
...
</div>
```

Then, in your **ts** file, add a function `trackByFn` or whatever name you prefer

```
trackByFn(index, material) {
  return index; // or material.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4" *ngFor="let material of materials" >
    <div class="card widget-statstic-card"  [style.background]="getColor()">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="card-header-left">
          <h3 class="d-inline-block">{{material.Prd_Type}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="text-left">
          <h3 class="d-inline-block">

          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> **TypeScript**

Assign value to randomItem only **once**

```
colors=['red','blue','green'];

  materials: any;
  randomItem: string;

  constructor(public http: HttpService) {
    this.http.getMethod('ProductType/get').subscribe((data => {
      this.materials = data;
      console.log(this.materials);
    }));
  }

  getColor(){

     if (!this.randomItem) {
        this.randomItem = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.colors.length)];
        console.log('s',this.randomItem);
     }
     return this.randomItem;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getColor();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In angular way, you can use ngClass for better rendering.

ex: [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}"

Depending on the condition it will call the class in css.

you can try this to solve the problem.

ex:

```
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
      <p [ngClass]="{'first': item.client=='Client', 'second': item.text=='data'}">{{item.client ? 'Client' : item.text}}</p>
    </button>
```

Any queries in ngClass please check this link https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

I hope this it will work

Comment: Brother there is no condition i have to every time show the user random background